# When do damage-over-time and healing-over-time effects calculate their effect?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Does a damage-over-time effect determine its damage and crit rate for the entire duration based on your stats at the time that it's cast? Or dynamically on a per-tick basis?

Put another way: is it optimal to pop adrenals/relics/timers before casting or refreshing DoTs? Or is it irrelevant?

Comment: Until they add a combat log type feature, I don't believe this question can be answered properly without a lot of hard work.

Comment: Benefits are given on a per tick basis but I don't know when and how the calculation happens. [Psychic projection](http://www.torhead.com/ability/9JBzIys/psychic-projection) is granted when a critical hit of weaken mind occures. [Weaken mind](http://www.torhead.com/ability/9dq2SnV/weaken-mind) does damage over time and the crits occure on a tik basis.

Comment: @Tom there's a bounty in it for you if you can formulate your comment into a more concrete answer by digging a little deeper and locate some sources :)

Comment: @yx. Actually, Toms comment is entirely orthogonal to the question. I know that each tick of a DoT can Crit independently. What I'm interested in us whether the *rate* at which this happens (or, since it's easier to test, the damage done) is calculated based on character stats at the time of the tick or the time of application.

Comment: @yx as OP said my comment is orthogonal. I stated that I don't know how and when the calculations happens. Which is the essence of the question(I assume). But I did not know that OP knows of the independent crits. Maybe you should add this to your post LessPop_MoreFizz.

Comment: I had thought it was implied.

Answer (score 4):

According to the ['Basic Mechanics' thread on sithwarrior.com](http://sithwarrior.com/forums/Thread-SW-TOR-Mechanics-The-Basics) opportunity to critically hit and the damage done is recalculated each time a DoT/HoT ticks.

**Under 'Debuffs and DOTs'**

> - Periodic abilities evaluate a person's buffs on each tick and not
>     just on the initial cast.

That would seem to answer your first question as no, it isn't set at the time it is cast.  And then yes, it is dynamic.

The answer to the 'put another way' question is significantly harder in my opinion.  There are some cases where it would be optimal to pop the buff before casting, and other times where it perhaps doesn't matter.  Any ability with an initial surge is going to benefit from the buff.

Comment: Yeah, obviously my rephrasing assumes we're talking about DoT effects that do a constant amount of damage, and not direct damage abilities with a dot that follows on.