# Relic effect end affecting current action

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

If I activate a relic, which has crit chance on it,  and, at the end of it's 20 second duration, I  am in the middle of an ability, is the chance of the ability to crit taken from when the ability was started(during which crit chance was higher) or from when it ends(when crit chance returns to it's normal amount)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do damage-over-time and healing-over-time effects calculate their effect?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/when-do-damage-over-time-and-healing-over-time-effects-calculate-their-effect)

Comment: It is slightly different. Even if it calculates it at the start of the ability, does the relic terminating during the same further affect the crit chance?

Comment: This is not a dupe. My question refers to DoT effects that have already been applied. This question is concerned with whether damage is calculated at cast start or cast completion for abilities with a cast time.

Comment: Unfortunately, until they add a combat log type feature, I don't believe this question can be answered properly without a lot of hard work.

Comment: @Sorean a combat log shouldn't be strictly necessary unless you need a particularly large data set. That need can be eliminated easily if you can figure out an ability that does a fixed amount (or very narrow range) of damage and which has a cast time. Back when WoW theorycraft was difficult, for instance, we used Kick, which did a precise (2 digit range) amount of damage to get exact armor formulae.

Comment: I understand that, but by hard work I meant, stripping armor and running a series of duels with people, seeing floating text damage and recording it as quick as you see it (or frapsing it) and then parsing the data later. A combat log makes it much easier to get that sort of data.

Comment: @Sorean While true, for a question like this one, you don't need a large dataset, or much in the way of recording/parsing - You just need to find an ability with a sufficiently narrow damage range. As for a target, ShipDroid has a defense chance of 0, and no defensive procs or abilities. So he's perfect for testing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few runs (103 to be precise), damage is applied on the tick that it happens. Meaning that for cast time abilities the damage applies after the cast time and is recalculated on every tick. It appears that if the relic is active for any part of the tick than it is applied to the entire tick so the optimum time to pop the relic/ability is the time between ticks as you get two extra ticks out of the relic.  Sadly, this means that if you have a cast time of four secs with three secs left on the relic, you see no benefit and should pop a different ability.

Comment: Are you referring to channeled spells for the 'every tick' comment? Out of curiosity, what spell/buff did you use for testing?

Comment: i used the dark heal on my sorcerer and I also ran about 53 runs on my bounty hunter using the flamethrower to see if the effect would last for a whole effect or cut off on a per tick basis.